# Java Image to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

How can an image file be converted into a PDF file using java? I am taking output from a graphic library. the output that I am able to export is in image formats like JPEG and PNG.
I want to convert that image file to PDF file.

Comment: itext would work depending on the license that is acceptable

Answer (score 1):

You can use Itext to add an Image to a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Use IText PDF API for Java you must first download the IText JAR file from the [IText website](http://itextpdf.com/)

First a Document instance is created.

Second, a PDFWriter is created, passing the Document instance and an OutputStream to its constructor. The Document instance is the document we are currently adding content to. The OutputStream is where the generated PDF document is written to.

```
 OutputStream file =     newFileOutputStream(newFile("/path/JavaGeneratedPDF.pdf"));      
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
```

Here make sure that you handle **DocumentException**

Inserting Image in PDF

```
Image image = Image.getInstance ("/Image.jpg");
        image.scaleAbsolute(200f, 100f); //image width,height
```

Here make sure that you handle **MalformedURLException**

Now Open PDF document,  add image and close document instance

```
document.open();                   
document.add(image);
document.close();
file.close();
```